# Suggestion to improve the CNN model architecture

Tags: python, model, conv-neural-network, training-data

I'm currently training the model to recognize the facial expressions and below is the CNN model architecture:

```
emotion_model = Sequential()

emotion_model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(48, 48, 1)))
emotion_model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
emotion_model.add(Dropout(0.1))

emotion_model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
emotion_model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
emotion_model.add(Dropout(0.1))

emotion_model.add(Flatten())
emotion_model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
emotion_model.add(Dropout(0.1))
emotion_model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))

cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)

emotion_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, decay=1e-6), metrics=['accuracy'])
print(emotion_model.summary())

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("/kaggle/working/model/model.h5", monitor='val_acc', 
verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                      min_delta=0,
                      patience=3,
                      verbose=1,
                      restore_best_weights=True
                      )

reduce_learningrate = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss',
                          factor=0.2,
                          patience=3,
                          verbose=1,
                          min_delta=0.0001)

callbacks_list = [checkpoint,reduce_learningrate]

history = emotion_model.fit_generator(generator=train_set,
                            steps_per_epoch=train_set.n//train_set.batch_size,
                            epochs=48,
                            validation_data = test_set,
                            validation_steps = test_set.n//test_set.batch_size,
                            callbacks=callbacks_list
                            )
```

Here is the result of the final epoch:

```
Epoch 48: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 8.191999053934474e-14.
1369/1369 [==============================] - 117s 86ms/step - loss: 0.4984 - accuracy: 0.8235 - val_loss: 1.2893 - val_accuracy: 0.5946 - lr: 4.0960e-13
```

Is there any suggestion on which layer or anything should be modified or added in order to improve the model accuracy?